# how to define a select component within a clr-tab

Tags: vmware-clarity

Tried to insert a "select" component under a tab. Basically, the tab just displays some dynamic forms. The select is a list of string for user selection  Looks like my definition is correct. Do not know why it messed up the whole angular/clarity UI page.

```
<clr-tab>
    <button clrTabLink>Submission Form</button>
    <clr-tab-content>
        &nbsp;<br>
    <label class="required" for="uniqueCertIDs">Unique Cert IDs</label>
    <div class="select">
        <select id="partnercertIDs" formControlName="EEPortalProductDetails">
        <option *ngFor="let ucertID of uniquecertIDs" [value]="ucertID.UniqueCertId">{{ucertID.UniqueCertId}} </option>
        </select>
     </div>
```

Very likely, the scope of the select portion is not correct. Failed finding related documentation.

Comment: Your sample is not showing the closing tags for these elements, so hard to say. Please provide either a reproduction of your issue in a Stackblitz, or more detail. I don't know what "why it messed up the whole angular/clarity UI page" means, is there an error or what?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say whats happening without a running example. 
I created a simple form with a select in a tab and it seems to be ok.

Here is the template code for my tabs:

```
          <clr-tabs>
            <clr-tab>
                <button clrTabLink id="link1">Tab1</button>
                <clr-tab-content id="content1" *clrIfActive>
                  <h3>Form 1</h3>
                  <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="selects_1">This is a select box</label>
                        <div class="select">
                          <select id="selects_1">
                            <option>Select</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let user of users" [value]="user">{{user}} </option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </clr-tab-content>
            </clr-tab>
        </clr-tabs>
```

You can see this running here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-tabs-form-select

If this doesn't solve your issue, can you fork the StackBlitz and recreate it there?

Comment: Now, the select data is populated correctly, but the ng-change event does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form [formGroup]="partnersForm" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="required" for="selects_1">Unique Cert IDs</label>
            <div class="select" >
                <select id="selects_1" formControlName="partnerFormCertIDs" ng-change="selectAction()">
                  <option *ngFor="let ucertID of uniquecertIDs" [value]="ucertID.UniqueCertId" >{{ucertID.UniqueCertId}}</option>
                </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and in my Session.ts file. Debug using console, the alert never shows up

```
selectAction() {
    alert("selected value changed !!!!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@nextgen-ui Regarding your second issue, the data binding syntax should be either `on-change` or `(change)`; `ng-change` is an AngularJS directive.

Please see [this Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-tabs-form-select-bscg6f?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: The method I defined in (change) need send a post message to the backend controller of the MVC model. Based on development and debug, I found this is not supported in angular framework.

Comment: I don't quite understand what is not supported; are you trying to use the select value as post data? That should work fine…   You might want to ask another question with further details.

Answer (score 0):

@Jose Gomes

The event is defined as updateCertData()

```
<form [formGroup]="partnersForm" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="required" for="selects_1">Unique Cert IDs</label>
                <div class="select">
                <select id="selects_1" formControlName="partnerFormCertIDs" (change)="updateCertData()">
                <option *ngFor="let ucertID of uniquecertIDs" [value]="ucertID.UniqueCertId">{{ucertID.UniqueCertId}}</option>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

And I defined a POST API in the event

```
updateCertData(){
    let selectedCertID = this.partnersForm.get('partnerFormCertIDs').value;
    for ( let partnerInfo of this.uniquecertIDs) {
        if(partnerInfo.UniqueCertId == selectedCertID){
            this.extractSubmit(this.cert);
            this.submit[0].Option[0].value = partnerInfo.ProductId;
            this.submit[0].Option[1].value = partnerInfo.ProductName;
            this.certsService.setSubmissionProduct(this.certId, this.submit);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

this.certsService.setSubmissionProduct is a POST API, sending data back to UI Server

```
setSubmissionProduct(sessionId: string, info:any){
    let body = {'submitConfig': info};
    let url = GLOBALS.baseUrl + "session/" + sessionId + "/submitproduct";
    return this.post(url, body);
}
```

The this.post never sends message to the controller successfully. I tried several other post methods, which works well in other logic part, but never sends message successfully if it is put within this "change" event.